# How to escape from an update message?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have following message in Progress-4GL:

```
DEF VAR L-temp AS CHARACTER.
MESSAGE "Give me information" UPDATE L-temp.
```

This shows an update message, which is fine, but when I try to escape from that message (e.g. I realise that I have clicked on the wrong button, launching this message), I can't hide that message:

[image]

How can I solve this (I simply want to remove the message from screen)?I can't add `VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX` as alert-boxes only can update logical variables and fields. Or is there a simple `Show-Dialogbox()` for such a case?

**Edit**
I tried replacing `UPDATE` by `SET` and viewing the whole thing as an alert-box, but this seems not to be allowed up (only logical variables and fields seem to be allowed).

**Edit 2**
Trying with `PROMPT-FOR` was not a good idea, because this seems to hide the rest of the window, while I want the message to be shown as some kind of a popup in top of the rest of my window/frame.

**Edit 3**
Also `System-Dialog` seems not to be a good idea, because all I want is to get a simple string.

Comment: Usually you would use F4 or ENTER to dismiss a MESSAGE.  But "escape from" and talk of hiding the message and data types is puzzling.  Perhaps you really want to do something different than escaping an "update message"?  Maybe you're trying to create a pop-up dialog of some sort?

Comment: @TomBascom: I'm sorry, but pressing F4 does not close the message (neither using ALT+F4 or Ctrl+F4). Do I need some configuration or whatever in order to make ±F4 work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit unfortunate that the 'close window' button does not by default, close the window. Even when a frame is defined as a modal `dialog-box`, the `window-close` event needs to be rerouted to `close`.

```
define frame frupdate
   cinfo as char label "Give me information" with side-labels
   with
      title "Message Update"
      view-as dialog-box      
   .

on "window-close" of frame frupdate 
   apply "close" to frame frupdate.
   
enable all with frame frupdate.
wait-for close of frame frupdate.
```

Comment: Just amazing how you always find such quick and exact answers for my problems :-)