# How to avoid an event being overwritten by a general one?

Tags: event-handling, openedge, progress-4gl

I have a main application, with following event:

```
ON ESCAPE ANYWHERE
```

I've just created a frame within a window, where I'd like to add an event:

```
ON ESCAPE ...
```

This, however, seems not to work as the main application already has an `ON ESCAPE ANYWHERE`. Is there something like `ON ESCAPE OVERWRITES DEFAULT` to create an event for my subwindow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424920563735.html) notes:

> A trigger defined with the ON statement remains in effect until one of
> the following occurs:
>
> - Another ON statement defines another trigger (or REVERT) for the same event and widget
> - For a non-persistent trigger, the procedure or trigger block in which the ON statement appears terminates

So I think your main application trigger is defined **after** your own trigger, overwriting it. If you can be specific enough, you should be fine:

```
on escape anywhere do:
   message 'escaping from anywhere' view-as alert-box.     
end.

define frame fr1
   cc1 as char 
   cc2 as char 
   with side-labels
   .   

do with frame fr1:

   enable all.   
   
   on escape of cc1 do:
      message "escaping from cc1 in frame 1" view-as alert-box.
   end.
   
end.

view frame fr1.
wait-for close of frame fr1.
```

Comment: Oops, apparently I've wrongly explained my situation: this question is a follow-up of the previous one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66639142/how-to-escape-from-an-update-message). In the mentioned frame, I've simply turned `on "window-close" of frame` into `on "window-close", ESCAPE of frame` but this seems not to work. I suspect this being caused by the mentioned general event in the main application, hence this new question. As you see I'm not looking to escape a single widget inside a frame, but I'm looking to escape the whole frame.

Comment: Creating a very short example illustrating your issue generally clears up any suspicions.